# case for setting non existing value in table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table 1 - id,field1

id field1
1  111
2  222
3  333
```

i am getting a junk value for field1 if there is no entry in that table(table1). i need to write a case statement in such a way that if id is present in that table it should return the value of field1 or else NULL.

for example : if i am selecting 1 it shoud give 111 . if the id is 4 then it should give null.

something like

```
case 
// check whether id is in table
if yes
  use the value
else
  null
```

. i am not sure how to write sql for this.

Comment: What does it have to do with C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Just select the field with an appropriate filter criterion:

```sql
SELECT field1 FROM table1 WHERE id = ?
```

In your application code, you can then test for the existence of a matching record by inspecting whether the resultset is non-empty.

Comment: i am using outer join in which it is resulting some id's that are not in that table. So, i have no other go. i ve to fix null for those ids

Comment: @srinath: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12863508/edit) to show this outer join.  Currently your question only shows a single table and no query, so it is hard to envisage how you are using an outer join or what is the problem you are encountering.